# performing a set of operations based on whether the item has an attachment or not

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

In power automate I have a flow as below:

1. Trigger when item created
   |
2. ```
       Get item
       |
   ```
3. ```
     Get attachements
       |
   ```
4. ```
     Get attachment content
       |
   ```
5. ```
     Start and wait for approval
       |
   ```
6. ```
     Switch which has 3 cases and then email are sent in each case
   ```

This works very well when there is an attachment. I can add the attachment link in the email by this flow. But when the item does not have an attachment, the flow fails after Get attachment content step 3, because there is no output from previous step.

Now I want to check if there is an attachment or not and perform all the steps from step 5 to step 6 irrespective of whether there is an attachment or not. I can do this by placing an IF ELSE CONDITION after step 3 and then based on it I can add or skip step 4. And then I need to add step 5 and step 6 under both if case and else case.

I am wondering if there is another way to do this rather than copying step 5 and step 6 twice under IF condition and ELSE condition. Hope I have explained my issue properly. I still cant attach screenshots here.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Please create the below Microsoft Flow:**

[image]

**2.Save and Test this flow**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Nisha Balan. Is there any problem?